# How to find a file inside installer's folder in Wix?

Tags: wix

Is there any way to find (and execute) a file that lies near installer ? My example of file structure:

```
MyInstaller.msi
Tools
  Tool.exe
```

I want to be able to find `Tools\Tool.exe` from MyInstaller.msi and launch it (if it exists) when user will click a button. I'm trying this

```
<Property Id="TOOL_EXE">
  <DirectorySearch Id="TOOL_PATH" Path="\Tool\">
    <FileSearch Id="TOOL_EXE_SEARCH" Name="tool.exe" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

but TOOL_EXE variable is empty.
Important note: I don't have this file in moment of creating installer, so I can't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only problem here is the `Path`-attribute, where you specified `\Tool\` as value. The leading backslash tries to search on the root, therefore it can't find the directory. Also leave away the final backslash: adding it the installer expects something to follow there. So try `.\Tool` instead.

You could also use the following (`SourceDir` is referencing the folder of the installation file, see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx)). It is possible though that  the property is not already available, didn't test this.

```
<Property Id="TOOL_EXE">
  <DirectorySearch Id="TOOL_PATH" Path="[SourceDir]Tool" Depth="0">
    <FileSearch Id="TOOL_EXE_SEARCH" Name="tool.exe" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Comment: [SourceDir] works, thanks ! I thought this variable is calculated while building the installer, not in runtime